# How can I save a project as an app?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

A totally noob question. I have recently finished my first calculator in `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript`. Now I want to have this calculator on iPhone. Is there any easy way to save the project as an app? Thank you!

Comment: cordova is the way to go as suggested. If you're starting a new app, would recommend using a framework that uses cordova, like [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/). There's also [Install to Homescreen](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen) from chrome, but it's for Android only I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). It should fit your needs perfectly.

I developed an [automated runner](https://github.com/dankreiger/cordova-runner) for Cordova that you might find useful. You can try that, or just simply follow the Cordova docs.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for the real noob, [Intels XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk/) is also someting to check out. It helps me to simply convert html, css, javascript to apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mac OS you can use Xcode with Storyboards just drag and drop UIWebView and set path to your html file.